# Return match position in String.scan

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to scan larger text documents for patterns expressed in regular expressions and extract a certain number of surrounding text tokens. At the moment I use String.scan to retrieve the matches, but this doesn't give me the position of the matched string in the document. Is there some elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477787/ruby-regular-expression-begin-method-a-bit-confusing).

It works on a match object.  `m.begin(1)`